# Disable Track and Trace in apache

Tags: apache, trace, user-tracking

I have Apache 2.2.22 in suse Linux. I want to disable track & trace in Apache and use 1- TraceEnable Off and 2- RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F] .
```

but of 2 way don't work.

Comment: In what files do you add TraceEnable?

Comment: added new answer for httpd 2.4

Answer (score 39):

In Apache2 you can just add `TraceEnable Off` in httpd.conf (end of file)

```
TraceEnable Off
```

To check if Trace is On/Off you can use Curl:

```
curl -v -X TRACE http://www.yourserver.com
```

Comment: The poster asked how to turn off TRACK and TRACE. Your solution does not turn off TRACK.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use curl to diagnose this. At least, 50% of the problem can be addressed this way...

Comment: Here is the solution is applied to main apache configuration not for individual hosts. It should be good approach if we choose a way to achieve same by each separate host configuration.

Comment: @AbhishekShah run the command `curl -i -X TRACK example.com` after the line in the conf above is applied and apache restarted, and it will now give a 501 error (should)... Track is theoretically usable by other modules AFAIK, but I don't know of any, so just check with that curl command I gave you to be sure if you like. Also, this answer is best... read about performance using Rewrite rules guys...

Answer (score 10):

You need to put `TraceEnable Off` in httpd.conf

Comment: @kghah This link might help you http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#traceenable

Answer (score 7):

To disable these methods, add the following lines for each virtual
host in your configuration file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)

RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

nessus said)))

Comment: configuration files! there can be multiple. Most commonly you have to add this to 2 configuration files:
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (for each virtual https host) and
/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf (for each virtual http host)
I did NOT have to edit httpd.conf.

Answer (score 3):

For Apache HTTPD 2.4:
`Require not method TRACE TRACK`

see [Require Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Comment: `TraceEnable off` also works in [Apache 2.4 per TraceEnable Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#traceenable) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a module is installed which supports TRACK, then TRACK is not supported by default by Apache, hence the only need to have the directive:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

However, for a belt-and-suspenders approach, also add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

This will disable both TRACE and TRACK.

Answer (score 0):

[View Demo Trace Using SSH Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwQgs.png)

TRACE is enabled by default in an apache installation.  There are two ways to remediate.  The first can be used if you are running Apache 1.3.34, 2.0.55, or anything in the 2.2 release.  Simply add the TraceEnable directive into your httpd.conf and set the value to Off.

> ```
> TraceEnable Off
> ```

add this line in httpd.conf

The first thing to do is make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded.  If mod_rewrite.so is missing from your apache configuration but you have it installed, (and your install location is /usr/local/apache), then add the following statement to your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule  rewrite_module  "/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_rewrite.so"
```

Then add the following as well to your httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Test With Curl Command

> curl -v -X TRACE http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already a few answers here, but I thought I'd chime in and add some additional options.

[Slipstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161120/4365209)'s approach is certainly the simplest approach here, so if you're seeking a quick and easy fix, there's your pot of gold.

### `TraceEnable` directive

As mentioned by a few people here, in Apache2, you can append the [TraceEnable directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#traceenable) to the end your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` file:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

### Rewrite Module

You can also add a rewrite configuration to your `VirtualHost` to explicitly block `TRACK` and `TRACE` requests:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACE)
    RewriteRule . * - [F]
</IfModule>
```

With this configuration, Apache catches all `TRACK` and `TRACE` requests, and replies with a [`403 Forbidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) error. None of the original request's content is echoed back.

### Rewrite Module (More Restrictive)

But, what I haven't seen anyone else suggest is explicitly passing the methods you want to allow. This is a slighly tighter fix, and is required for PCI compliance:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

This will reject any request which is using a method not specified in the directive. Again, the original request content is not echoed back, and the server responds with a `403 Forbidden` error.

Something to keep in mind is that for production systems is that **RewriteEngine can be processor intensive**. This is generally not much of an issue because the increase would be milliseconds (if not microseconds), but something to be mindful of if you have loads of rewrites.

*Note: For the above rewrite configurations, you'll need to uncomment the `LoadModule` or `AddModule` (depending on your setup) directives in your Apache config for `rewrite_module`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the mod_allowmethods found in apache 2.3+

```
<Location "/">
   AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS
</Location>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html