# Disable TRACE/TRACK HTTP methods for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It is a security best practice to disable the HTTP TRACE and TRACK methods in production.  What is the best way to do this in an Apache2-based Elastic Beanstalk Deployment (such as Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `TraceEnable Off` ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161120/2800876)) will only disable TRACE and not TRACK.  You'll need to use rewrite engine for TRACK requests.

Add the following to one of your .config files in `.ebextensions`:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/disable_trace_track.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            TraceEnable Off
            RewriteEngine on
            <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'TRACK'">
              RewriteRule .* - [F]
            </If>
```